# Ionic 1: How to define navigation for same state from different tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a tabbed application with tabs such as Explore and Search. I also have attraction page which can be opened from both the Explore and Search tabs. How do I  defined the attraction page state so it can be opened from both tabs and won't change the active tab once the attraction state is being navigated to?